# Has the knowledge of applicability of an idea helped you learn/appreciate a concept? If yes, how?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy

Can you please elaborate your answer with specific examples?

PS: Sorry, i couldn't find the exact tags.  Please excuse me if this question is not suited for the site.

Comment: Any calculus text teaches calculus through the basic idea of velocity and displacement. At least 70-80% of people understand calculus through physics.